# Notation: What's $]a,b[$

Tags: notation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about set notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244644/question-about-set-notation)

Suppose we have that $\ f:]a,b[\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

What is $]a,b[$?

I know what $[a,b]$, $(a,b)$, $[a,b)$ are.

I would usually google but I don't know what keyword to use. Let me know if this is too simple/inappropriate for Math.SE and I'll delete.

Comment: This $]a,b[$ European notation (French, if I recall correctly) for the open interval $(a,b)$. It's sometimes still used in the literature, but I think parentheses carried the day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\mathopen]a, b\mathclose[ \;= (a, b)$

$\mathopen]a, b\mathclose[\;\;$ denotes the open interval of real numbers $(a, b)= \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\}.$

Such notation is used by some to *disambiguate* between the *ordered pair* $(a, b)$ -- which is merely a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ -- and the *open interval* $(a, b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Likewise:

- $[a, b\mathclose[ = [a, b)$
- $\mathopen]a, b] = (a, b]$

Comment: Any ideas on how to properly format this in latex? Because $]0,1[\to]0,1[$ looks like it's about some element $[\to]$.

Comment: @amWhy: Is this notaion lost in Mathematics contexts? Nice notation.

Comment: @akkkk: Use `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`, as in `\mathopen]a, b\mathclose[`. See my edit of the answer. (You can also right click on a formula and use the popup menu to see the LaTeX.)

Comment: @Harald That beats brute-force spacing!